# Reading XML file with PHP

Tags: php, xml, file-get-contents

I'm trying to read an XML file with PHP but I get this error and don't know what I've done wrong.

```
Warning: file_get_contents(username:password@http://services.mobile.de/1.0.0/ad/search) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /www/htdocs/*******/mobile.php on line 11

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML' in /www/htdocs/*******/mobile.php:12 Stack trace: #0 /www/htdocs/w00f6d79/mobile.php(12): SimpleXMLElement->__construct('') #1 {main} thrown in /www/htdocs/*******/mobile.php on line 12
```

My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>mobile.de</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
$url = "username:password@http://services.mobile.de/1.0.0/ad/search";
$xml = file_get_contents($url);
$data = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
echo $data->children('ad', true)->ad->vehicle->class->children()->children('resource', true)->local-description;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The url `username:password@http://services.mobile.de/1.0.0/ad/search` is not accessible.

Comment: `file_get_contents` knows nothing about creds. One should use [`curl` functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) for that.

Comment: 'username' and 'password' are wildcards.

Comment: Is a local or remote file ?

Comment: @Micheled'Amico It can read from several sources including http using the stream wrappers.

Comment: @mudasobwa wrong, you can provide the authentication in the context argument.

Answer (score 0):

The file that your are trying to get is not found on the server.

1) The file that you requested / redirected to, was not found on the server
2) Whatever that is returned from the server was not valid XML content

Please check the file's location and your server configuration.

Answer (score 0):

`username:password@http://services.mobile.de/1.0.0/ad/search` is not a valid URL. Some HTTP clients understand `http://username:password@services.mobile.de/1.0.0/ad/search`, but the the authentication should be in the HTTP headers - not the URL.

```
$authorization = base64_encode('username:password');
$options = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Authorization: Basic ".$authorization."\r\n"
  )
);
$context = stream_context_create($options);
$data = file_get_contents(
  'http://services.mobile.de/1.0.0/ad/search', false, $context
);
```